# Refresh Teiid's SYS.* tables

Tags: teiid

I'm using Teiid 9.0.2 for data virtualization. I've created Datasource, deployed VDB and then created new table in datasource (MySQL/Postgresql). The new table isn't listed in VDB's SYS.Tables and SYS.Columns. Is there any way to refresh these tables?

Comment: Please provide some code of what you've done.

Comment: Code http://pastebin.com/3jrp8Eif

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow !! Since external links are discouraged (they could get broken), I've copied your code inside the question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to **restart Application Server** or **re-deploy VDB**. It will reload metadata when you redeploy VDB.

`ExecutionFactory.getMetadata(...)` loads the meta-data and it is invoked on deployment of VDB